# Ошибка при передачи одного из методов обьекта ошибка temp undefined

Tags: reactjs, get

Всем привет. Вдруг кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой. Получаю данные, достаю  с этих данных name страны и прокидываю в компоненту чтобы отобразить, дальше пытаюсь достать значение для температуры и все крашится ошибка `temp`.

Код `Home.js`:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './Home.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import Weather from "../Weather/Weather";

const Home = () => {
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);
  const [city,setCity] = useState(false)
  const fetchData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
     await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&mode=json&appid=91bc0de7ce6fb21698914f14935ed7f1`)
         .then(res => setData(res.data));
  }

  console.log(data);

  return <section className='home'>
    <div className="home__search">
      <form onSubmit={fetchData}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className='home__search-input'
          placeholder='Введите город '
          onChange={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button  className='home__search-btn'>Узнать погоду</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <Weather cityName={data.name} temp={data.main.temp} />
  </section>
}

export default Home
```

**Когда не передаю значение** `temp={data.main.temp}` тогда все работает вот фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код ошибки. У меня есть подозрения, что `data.main` у вас `undefined`, либо в объекте `data.main` нет проперти `temp` - оттуда и  `undefined`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Comment: У вас в объекте `data` нет проперти `main`, отсюда и ошибка

Comment: я понимаю что в data нет проперти но , не понимаю как исправить

Comment: Если этого проперти там нет, то либо его нужно добавить, либо не пытаться читать то, чего нет

Comment: Проблема в том,что данные получаем после ввода города и отправки , а когда мы ренденрим в самом начале ,то этих данных еще нет, как по типу сказать подождать пока произойдет запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Вам *@Denis Bubnov* в комментариях намекнул, что не стоит обрабатывать те данные, которых еще нет или вообще может не быть. если Вы знаете, что такое может случиться в Вашем проекте, то есть лишь 2 выхода:

- не отображать тот блок, который будет выводить потенциально отсутствующие данные, например внутри компонента `Weather` прописать условие `temp && <div>{temp}</div>`, которое будет проверять на наличие *пропса* `temp`. если оно есть - отображать блок с этими данными. нет - не отображать.
- задайте *пропсы* для по-умолчанию для потенциально отсутствующих данных (а лучше вообще для всех *пропсов*, так как жизнь непредсказуемая) и ошибок быть не должно. как задавать *пропсы* по умолчанию сможет посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) (ниже чуть пролистаете и увидите)